# Hide columns in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to add a row with multiple columns. My first column - 'col-sm-1' will save as a padding and I need to hide it. But, when I add the col-sm-4, its not hidden.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-1 hidden" style="background-color:lavender;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" style="background-color:lavender;">text
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont use a column as padding.
delete the first column and add the class
col-sm-offset-1 to go along with the class of col-sm-4

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any bootstrap helper classes that allow you to do this.

It's easy enough to fix with your own css and an additional class.

```
.hidden-helper {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

**DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/brvpppcv/

However if you are just trying to push the column over you should use the grid offsets.

example: `col-sm-offset-1`

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting